# Multiple Word2007 references in the Running Object Table

Tags: windows, automation, ms-word, word-2007, dynamic-data-exchange

Contrary to earlier versions (see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238975)), I find that Word2007 places one entry into the Running Object Table for each instance of WinWord.exe that is running. (Using IROTVIEW.exe supplied with MS VC 6.0!) 
I am trying to build an application that automates Word, and I would like to keep a hidden instance of Word unavailable to the user, while co-existing with a separate visible instance. Is there any way of preventing Word from registering itself in the ROT, or alternatively of ensuring that when the user double-clicks on a Word document, it is the visible instance that opens the document? 

On reflection perhaps I should be asking a different question: when broadcasting a DDE message and there are multiple windows with the correct Application name, what determines which window gets to process the message first? I ask because I realise that the File Association for doc, docx extensions etc indicates that DDE will be used to open the document.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't understand the question but a non visible instance is hidden for all practical purposes. The user won't be able to open that instance or any documents associated with it.

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim currentDocument As Document

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 3
        Dim newApplication As Word.Application
        Set newApplication = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        Set currentDocument = newApplication.Documents.Add
        currentDocument.Range.InsertAfter "New instance " & i

        If i = 2 Then
            currentDocument.Windows(1).Visible = False
        Else
            currentDocument.Windows(1).Visible = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```